# Sending Azure Push Notifications to Production Apps Through Azure Portal

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I set up the Azure environment, with the Notifications Hub and a Mobile Backend. It works perfectly and simply with the "Test Send" feature, where I receive a notification on my phone, and can dismiss it or click on it to open the app. All I am looking for is a feature similar to this, but with production capabilities. I don't want to setup more infrastructure, and write all this code, just to send the most basic of push notifications, so I am wondering how this may be done in the Microsoft Azure portal? Thanks!

**Edit 1:** to anyone struggling with the same problem, Microsoft also offers a service called Visual Studio App Center, which has the extavt functionality I desired, and is super easy to implement. For some reason it was listed very highly during my searches, so I never knew it existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that there is ony "Test Send" feature in Azure portal. You need to accomplish this by using [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-push) or [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/dn495628(v%3Dazure.100)). Normally, you would send notifications using a backend server. For some cases, you might want to be able to [send push notifications directly from the client application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-gcm-get-started#optional-send-push-notifications-directly-from-the-app).

Comment: If you’re Microsoft partner, I find a free channel to solve azure queries: aka.ms/devchat. They support online chat and email.